# Squeeze Theorem doubt when it doesn't satisfies the inequality

Tags: calculus

Suppose that f is a function defined in the open interval (0,1) except possibly at $x=1/2$. Suppose that the functions h and g are also defined on the interval (0,1) as it follows:

$
   h(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{-4x+12}{25} &  if x \neq 1/2 \\
       0 &  if x=1/2
     \end{array}
   \right.
 $

$
   g(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \frac{2x-1}{2x^2+3x-2}&  if x \neq 1/2 \\
       -8 &  if x=1/2
     \end{array}
   \right.
 $

We know that except for $x=1/2$, we have $ h(x) \leq f(x) \leq g(x) $. Is it possible to determine the limit when $x->1/2$ of $f(x)$?

I am having trouble with this question. Because at 1/2 the function do not satisfy the inequalities, but in some places it says that it does not matter if it doesn't satisfy it at that particular point. But then I got confused about the limits of h and g. Those functions are not continuous at 1/2, but what happens to their limits the  approaching to 1/2? I just got really confused by this problem. Can somebody give me some orientation?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the main trouble you're having is with the idea of limits themselves. Remember that with limits, if you have $\lim_{x \to c} h(x)$, then it doesn't matter what $h(c)$ evaluates to. The only thing that matter is what $h(x)$ "approaches". (similarly with $g(x)$)

Plus, since the result of the squeeze theorem (as stated by Adriano) gives you $\lim_{x \to 1/2} f(x)$, it doesn't matter what $f(\frac{1}{2})$ evaluates to, only its limit.

Therefore, even though $\frac{2}{5}$ isn't between $g(\frac{1}{2})$ and $f(\frac{1}{2})$, it is between their limits at $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Since $h(x) \leq f(x) \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in (0, \frac{1}{2}) \cup (\frac{1}{2}, 1)$ and:
$$
\lim_{x \to 1/2} h(x) = \frac{2}{5} = \lim_{x \to 1/2} g(x)
$$
it follows by [the Squeeze Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Statement) that:
$$
\lim_{x \to 1/2} f(x) = \frac{2}{5}
$$